# Is the permittivity of crystal ONLY related to the small group of the $\Gamma$ point?

Tags: solid-state-physics, group-theory, crystals

Is the permittivity of crystal **only** related to the small group of the $\Gamma$ point, even for crystals with non-symmorphic space groups?